# Disable button For 6 hours accordingly to international time

Tags: java, android, button

I am very new to Android. I want to disable a button after it pressed and re-enable it after 6 hours/1 day accordingly to system time. It's like giving reward to the user every day. User can only press the reward button once in a day.
When I re-open the app before 6 hours the button enables again. Please Help!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

    Button mybutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
    final long currenttime= System.currentTimeMillis();

    final SharedPreferences mysharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("timeinfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=mysharedPreferences.edit();
    final long secondtime=mysharedPreferences.getLong("writetime",currenttime);

     mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(final View v)
        {
            editor.putLong("writetime",currenttime);
            v.setClickable(false);

            if (currenttime-secondtime>300000)
            {
                v.setClickable(true);
            }
            else
            {
                v.setClickable(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're saving time values as milliseconds, for that the comparison value (6 hours) will be  `" 21600000 "` .

Answer (score 0):

You can save the time when you press the button to sharedpreferences.
Then next time you create the activity/fragment, you read the value and subtract it to the current time. If it's more than 6 hours, you enable the button, if not, you disable it.
Disadvantage: if the device is rooted and the user changes the saved value, they have infinite button clicks. You can find info about encrypting the shared prefs so you can work around this, for example here: https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/securing-sharedpreferences-in-android-a21883a9cbf8

```
myButton.setEnabled(false) // turn it off by default
if (currenttime-secondtime>=21600000) { // check if it can be enabled; 21600000ms is 6 hours
    myButton.setEnabled(true);  // wait time is up, enable button
    editor.putLong("writetime", currenttime); // since we enabled the button right now, we save the current time
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // user can click the button, add listener
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            // do whatever you want to do when the user can click the button
        }
    });
}
```

I'd go with something like this (replacing the mybutton.setOnClickListener(...) part)

Comment: On a note the code sample you provided, don't check the time in onclicklistener, but check it before and enable/disable the button accordingly. After that you can add your listener, the button will be disabled if it should be disabled and the listener code won't run.

Comment: I know I did stupid mistake in my code, but can you re-arrange my code and write the correct code for me please.I think I am close to the solution.